# SQL Server with one ethernet output and Webserver with another ethernet output

Tags: sql-server, iis-7.5, ssrs, ssis

**Scenario:**

I have one server which is virtualizated using VMWare ESXi. Specs:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- SQL Server Standard 2012
- IIS 7.5
- Hosting a MVC and a Webform application (using Reporting Services)
- Integration Services is also heavily used.
- Everything on the same virtual machine instance
- Server machine has 4 Gigabit ethernet ports
- Performance and scalability is not right now much of an issue (maybe in 2 years).

**Problem:**

I have an SSIS Package that needs to establish a VPN connection (using Cisco VPN connection by the way) to get data from a external Oracle database. This VPN doesn't have Internet access and that means that my machine doesn't have internet connection, so my web application is down until the extraction is done (which is about 5 mins).

I was thinking in how I can create a solution to keep my web server alive while I'm running the SSIS packages? Maybe configuring SQL to use a different ethernet interface and IIS another? If this is possible, how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can configure the VPN client not to change your default gateway, you shouldn't have any interruption to your internet connection.

The only reason you lose your internet connection is because the VPN client adds a new default route to the VPN server at the other end of the tunnel, forcing all traffic through the VPN.

Almost all VPN clients I've ever seen have a way to turn this feature off, either a checkbox somewhere for "force all traffic through VPN", or by editing the VPN's configuration file.

Comment: Thanks, once I get home, I'll get a look to this. I'll post my founds.